# posting data to a web page,need an alternative

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

To request some data from a web server, we can use the GET method,like

> www.example.com/?id=xyz

but I want to request the data like

> www.example.com/xyz

How can it be achieved in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file in your root directory and call it .htaccess. Put this in it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [R=301,L]
```

If someone goes to www.example.com/xyz and xyz is not a directory or a file it will load /index.php?xyz instead. It will be completely transparent to your users.

Comment: could you please explain in detail?

Comment: The first line checks to see if xyz is a file. If it is the file will load normally. If not the second lne checks to see if xyz is a directory. If it is it will load normally. If it isn't it will pass xyz as a GET parameter to index.php.

Answer (score 1):

You could use mod-rewrite, some more info is here

http://www.trap17.com/index.php/php-mod-rewrite-tutorial_t10219.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure "posting" the data is the right terminology, but you can use Apache mod_rewrite to make URLs like '/xyz' direct to your PHP application. For example, place a .htaccess file in your web root with the following,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the URL specified is available in `$_GET['url]`.

Comment: i did not mean POST by 'posting' in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve what you want with the GET method, as PHP will always append form data in a query string to the end of the URL specified in your form's `action` attribute.

Your best bet is to post the data to a handler (i.e. `www.example.com/search`) and then use that page to redirect to the correct page.

So if you entered a query for `hello+world`, that variable would be passed to your `/search` page and processed by the PHP script to re-direct to `/hello+world`.

Of course, you're going to need the correct `.htaccess` rules in place to handle searches like this, as well as sanitizing data.

Comment: what i want is i want to replace www.example.com/id=xyz with www.example.com/xyz ,ie i want to type the latter url in the browser and get the result rather than the first method.

Comment: Should just be a case of a `mod_rewrite` rule if you're hand-typing URLs. Chances are I've read the original post wrong.